# Installing QEMU/KVM to Ubuntu headless server 16.04

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have installed Ubuntu server 16.04 as my main OS, and I have installed all the following packages:

```
qemu-kvm, libvirt-bin, virtinst, bridge-utils, cpu-checker
```

I did the `virt-install` of the VM. It is 2 core hdd size = 8 gig

My installation has been running for approximately 30 hours.

Server specifications:

```
2 x Xeon 5690 
96 gig ram 
raid 0
2x hdd 15k
```

How much time does the domain installation take?